# Spyder no starting in Ubuntu bu GUI

Tags: unity, python, launcher, icons, spyder

I'm not able to launch Spyder by GUI in Ubuntu through the icon is there. When I click on the icon, spyder icon appears on the launcher and disappears soon. Nothing happens then. I had installed Spyder by `sudo apt-get install spyder`. But when I try to open it by the terminal, by the command 'spyder' it opens, though the python console is not available. To avail Python console, I want it to open by GUI.

When I tried installing by Ubuntu software, on searching for 'spyder', it said, "No application found".

How to launch spyder from the GUI?